# Yahoo mail ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: google-chrome, email, yahoo-mail

For the last maybe 10 days I have been having trouble accessing `Yahoo mail`.  I can sign in but I get this message:

```
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Eventually I can access the inbox by refreshing the screen maybe six times.  Then only maybe the first 20 email messages are visible in the inbox.  Messages after that are just kind of greyed-out.

I thought maybe my account was nearly 'full'.  So, I deleted maybe a couple thousand messages.  But that does not seem to have helped.  I have been using mostly `Google Chrome` to access the `Yahoo` account, but I get the same message using `Microsoft Edge`.

I am using a `Windows 10 Dell laptop`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an ideal solution.  But I have found a functional one.

Step 1.  Search for 'yahoo mail' in Google

[image]

Step 2. Click on 'Mail'

This will bring up a screen saying a page is not available.

[image]

Step 3. Click on 'Go to Inbox'

This will open the inbox almost immediately.